# Find the eccentricity of the ellipse.

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry, conic-sections

The tangent at $(a\cos\theta, b\sin\theta)$ on the ellipse $\dfrac{x^2}{a^2}+\dfrac{y^2}{b^2}=1$ meets the auxiliary circle in two points. The chord joining them subtends a right angle at the centre. Find the eccentricity of the ellipse.

Answer I got is $\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1+\sin^2\theta}}$. Is it correct?

Comment: Yes, you are correct. See here also: https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h247089_tangent_to_an_ellipse